# Is it possible to reuse <ng-content></ng-content> in component template? Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am curious is there any way to reuse twice **ng-content** in component? Or to assign it to variable inside component constructor?

Something like:

```js
@Component({
    selector: "component"
})
@View({
    template: `<ng-content></ng-content> and again <ng-content></ng-content>`
})
```

Comment: yes we can use more than one ng-content in our template but if we use more than one then we have to mention the name of the ng-content. best tutorial for ng-content i have found is here http://angular-tips.com/blog/2015/09/migrating-directives-to-angular-2/

Comment: Yes, i also found this.

<pre> <my-component>
  <div content-a>
    A
  </div>
  <div content-b>
    B
  </div>
</my-component>

and in component:

<ng-content select="[content-a]"></ng-content></pre>

Comment: yes this also can use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, i also found this.

```
<my-component> <div content-a> A </div> </my-component>
```

and in component:

```
<ng-content select="[content-a]"></ng-content>
```

Answer (score 19):

There is also an other way of doing it with the help of `ng-template`

Wrap the `ng-content` inside `ng-template` and use `ngTemplateOutlet` with `ng-container`

Example:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="YourCondition" *ngTemplateOutlet="content"></ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="!YourCondition" *ngTemplateOutlet="content"></ng-container>

<ng-template #content><ng-content></ng-content></ng-template>
```

Use this as,

```
<my-component>Anything</my-component>
```

Comment: it works well, but newest angular versions (8+) will fail cause of two bindings on the same ng-container. Need to wrap into additional container:  `<ng-container *ngIf><ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet></ng-container></ng-container>`